# c++ std::wcout. fail and bad bits are set

Tags: c++

Why `L"&'v\x5\x17\x15-\x1dR\x14]Dv\x1991q-5Xp\x13\x172"` value in a container of the type `std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >` yields setting bad and fail bits in `std::wcout` when being output?

Comment: What is the compiler, the OS, and the locale? (on my gcc-4.8.1/linux/utf-8, it is printed to wcout without any issues)

Comment: provide a working example

Comment: @Cubbi Plus how the file was opened.  (I don't see anything problematic off hand, but it's not generally safe to output arbitrary control characters to a file opened in text mode.)

Comment: Windows 7, MSVS2012, locale is Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what really happens in your code but on windows you have to use platform-specific functions to enable UTF-16 support in console because it uses your default ANSI codepage, i.e. cp1251 (see http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx). This solves the problem with bad bits:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

/*...*/
_setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );
/*...*/
```

You also have to pick the correct font for the console otherwise some of the characters will look like squares. For example, you may pick Lucida Console or Consolas but if you look at the character map, you will see that there are no Chinese characters and many others too in these fonts. If you want to change font to something different try doing this https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-xp-console-font but beware (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247815).

Also remember that Unicode support on POSIX-like OSes and Windows is different. Windows uses UTF-16 encoding stored in `wchar_t` types while most POSIX operating systems use UTF-8 and `char` for storage.